# ColumnSeries from Silverlight Charting Toolkit problems

Tags: silverlight, charts

I'm new to Silverlight development and am currently venturing into the Charting territory.
I've been following several tutorials that show how easy it is to bind a ColumnSeries to a datasource using ItemsSource (http://silverlight.net/forums/t/44166.aspx).

I'm programatically adding a chart to a canvas.

```
Chart BudgetChart = new Chart { Title = "budget", MaxHeight= 200, MaxWidth=500};
ColumnSeries cs = new ColumnSeries();
BudgetChart.Series.Add(cs);
cs.Title = "blarg";
cs.ItemsSource = o.Budget; //returns List<Budget>
cs.IndependentValueBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Budget");
cs.DependentValueBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Year");
```

This code compiles fine. However, when I debug it, this error is throw
However, I've been experiencing a lot of difficulty with ItemsSource. Each time I assign the ItemsSource, I get a error stating that it's Sys.InvalidOperationException: ManagedRuntimeError error #4004 in control 'Xaml1': System.NullReferenceException System.NullReferenceException: Object not set to an instance of an object. at System.Windows.Control.DataVisualization.Charting.ColumnSeries.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__4()

Please help, this error is driving me crazy!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the ItemsSource assignment to after the bindings.  Also Add the series to the chart after having configured its bindings.

```
Chart BudgetChart = new Chart { Title = "budget", MaxHeight= 200, MaxWidth=500};
ColumnSeries cs = new ColumnSeries();
cs.Title = "blarg";
cs.IndependentValueBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Budget");
cs.DependentValueBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Year");

BudgetChart.Series.Add(cs);

cs.ItemsSource = o.Budget; //returns List<Budget>
```

Comment: Hi AnthonyWJones,
Thanks for your reply. I tried doing as you've suggest, but the problem still persist. Any other suggestions that I may try?

Comment: If it's any help, I'm using the March release of the Toolkit.

Comment: I've finally learned how to read. I was binding wrongly. I got confused between the Dependent and Independent bindings.
Thank you for your help AnthonyWJones.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your first data point does not contain a null/Nothing in the dependent value.
The error occurs when the chart tries to "sniff" the type of dependent axes required, and fails.

```
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeriesWithAxes.GetAxes(DataPoint firstDataPoint, Func`2 independentAxisPredicate, Func`1 independentAxisFactory, Func`2 dependentAxisPredicate, Func`1 dependentAxisFactory)
```

at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.ColumnSeries.GetAxes(DataPoint firstDataPoint)

There seems to be no workaround. One option is to subclass a LinearAxis which overrides CanPlot(value). Currently NumericAxis.CanPlot fails for value==null

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Returns a value indicating whether a value can plot.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value to plot.</param>
    /// <returns>A value indicating whether a value can plot.</returns>
    public override bool CanPlot(object value)
    {
        double val;
        return ValueHelper.TryConvert(value, out val);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<toolkit:Chart Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Name="columnChart" Grid.Column="0" Width="400" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <toolkit:Chart.Series>
                    <toolkit:ColumnSeries 
                        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" 
                                     DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" IsHitTestVisible="True" IsSelectionEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="ColumnSeries_SelectionChanged">
                    </toolkit:ColumnSeries>
                </toolkit:Chart.Series>
                <toolkit:Chart.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:Chart">
                        <chartingPrimitivesToolkit:EdgePanel x:Name="ChartArea">
                            <Grid Canvas.ZIndex="-1" Style="{TemplateBinding PlotAreaStyle}" />
                            <Border Canvas.ZIndex="10" BorderBrush="#FF919191" BorderThickness="1" />
                        </chartingPrimitivesToolkit:EdgePanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </toolkit:Chart.Template>
                <toolkit:Chart.Axes>
                    <toolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Interval="10" />
                </toolkit:Chart.Axes>
            </toolkit:Chart>

List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> lkvpGraph1 = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> { };
            KeyValuePair<int, string> kvpGraph1 = new KeyValuePair<int, string>();

            List<string> lstJob = new List<string>();
            lstJob = lR1Acceptance.Where(r1 => r1.FCode == Facility).Select(r1 => r1.Job_No).Distinct().ToList();
            double nWeeks = Math.Round((dtToDate - dtFromDate).Days / 7.0, 0);
            nWeeks++;

            foreach (string job_no in lstJob)
            {
                int TotalSubmission = lR1Acceptance.Where(rr => rr.Job_No == job_no).Count();
                int TotalR1Accepted = lR1Acceptance.Where(rr => rr.Round_No == 1 && rr.Result == "A" && rr.Job_No == job_no).Count();
                int dAcceptance = (int)Math.Round(TotalR1Accepted * 100.0 / TotalSubmission, 0);
                if (TotalSubmission != 0)
                {
                    kvpGraph1 =
                             new KeyValuePair<int, string>(dAcceptance, job_no);
                    lkvpGraph1.Add(kvpGraph1);
                }

            }
            ((ColumnSeries)columnChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = lkvpGraph1;
```